# NSArray sorted by function

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, sorting

I have an `NSArray` containing several `NSDictionary` instances. Each `NSDictionary` has, among other fields, an object named `rating` and one `numberOfVotes`(both are `int`). How can I sort the array so it gets sorted by `rating`/`numberOfVotes`? More generically, can I sort it by doing an operation like mentioned above? Or would it be better to just add another object to each `NSDictionary` with the value of each operation and then sort by that?

Thanks

EDIT - I have added the following. Still not sorting properly. One question: Should this work for more than 2 objects in my array. (The number of objects will vary)

```
    [sortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id dict1, id dict2)
{
    MyObj *obj1 = (MyObj *)dict1;
    MyObj *obj2 = (MyObj *)dict2;

    int rating1 = obj1.rating.intValue;
    int rating2 = obj2.rating.intValue;

    int number1 = obj1.number_of_votes.intValue;
    int number2 = obj2.number_of_votes.intValue;

    double key1 = ((double)rating1)/number1;
    double key2 = ((double)rating2)/number2;

    if (key1 < key2)
    {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }

    if (key2 < key1)
    {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return NSOrderedSame;

}];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a custom comparator to use a composite sorting key of the kind that you are looking for. If there is no good reason to have that sorting key in the dictionary, other than  performing the sort, do not add an item to the dictionary.

```
array = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    int rating1 = [[obj1 objectForKey:@"rating"] intValue];
    int numberOfVotes1 = [[obj1 objectForKey:@"numberOfVotes"] intValue];
    int rating2 = [[obj2 objectForKey:@"rating"] intValue];
    int numberOfVotes2 = [[obj2 objectForKey:@"numberOfVotes"] intValue];
    double key1 = ((double)rating1)/numberOfVotes1;
    double key2 = ((double)rating2)/numberOfVotes2;
    if (key1 > key2) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }

    if (key1 < key2) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

**Note:** The `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` method does not sort the array in place; instead, it returns a sorted *copy*. If you would like an in-place sorting, use `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: @AndreiFilip Yes, this will work for as many items as necessary. However, this does not *sort* the array in place; it returns a sorted copy of the array.

Comment: Its awesome cos it uses blocks,ftw !! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The adequate way would be using blocks like this

```
NSArray *sortedArray;

sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    float first = [[(NSDictionary*)a objectForKey:@"rating"] floatValue]/
                      [[(NSDictionary*)a objectForKey:@"numberOfVotes"] floatValue];
    float second = [[(NSDictionary*)a objectForKey:@"rating"] floatValue]/
                      [[(NSDictionary*)a objectForKey:@"numberOfVotes"] floatValue];
return [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:first] compare: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:second]];
}];
```

you may find more ways to compare:

[How to sort an NSMutableArray with custom objects in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it)

Answer (score 0):

The family of methods you seek are prefixed with `sortedArray`.

For a *function* (which is one of multiple options), see: `-[NSArray sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:]`.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit*: If you want to do `rating` divided by `numberOfVotes`, you will have to sort by a function or comparator block or replace the dictionary with a model object which has a method to calculate `rating / numberOfVotes`.

Use [`NSSortDescriptor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
 NSArray *sorted = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"rating" ascending:YES],
    [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"numberOfVotes" ascending:YES],
    nil]
 ];
```

Comment: It looks like the OP wants to divide `rating` by the `numberOfVotes`, not resolve conflicts by `numberOfVotes`.

Comment: Ah. Then the OP will have to use a comparator/function (see @dasblinkenlight) or go from a dictionary to a model object and define a method that calculates the appropriate value to rank by.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering data is one of the essential tasks in computing.

You can sort it several ways.

1. [**NSPredicate**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html)

   You can see examples [here](https://sites.google.com/a/pintailconsultingllc.com/objective-c-and-cocoa/Home/nspredicate-examples)
2. [**NSSortDescriptor**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

   You can see examples [here](http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.in/2011/08/nssortdescriptor-example.html)
3. **Regular Expressions**
4. **Set Operations**
5. **Key-Value Coding**

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should substitute `NSDictionary` by a custom object, with properties like `rating` and `numberOfVotes`. Then, you could declare a method `compare:` on this custom object and use as the selector to sort the array.

You can use a block code to sort the objects but abstracting the implementation into a custom object is much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

you can use NSSortDescriptor here for sorting for example your array that containing several NSDictionnaries name is dataArray.

```
 NSSortDescriptor * descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:rating
                            ascending:YES];
 NSArray * keyArrray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor, nil];
 NSArray * sortedArray = [dataArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:keyArrray];
```

With the help of NSSortDescriptor we can sort any data type key value pair.